# How do I fill an array with binary data streaming from websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, websocket

I got a continuous stream of byte data receiving from websocket.
When I view the data with this function:

```
document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML + msg + "<br />";
```

It would look like this:

```
-0.00005645785104823496
0.00000906544783255643
-0.001234972515485563
0.00000008534781277461
.
.
.
```

I want to fill it in an array that would look like

```
var inp = new Array(event.data)
  , arr = new Float32Array()
  ;
for(var i = 0;i <arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = inp[i];
}
```

How do I fill the ***inp[i]*** array with data receiving from websocket.

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired outcome? do you need the `-` and the `.`?

Comment: I want to fill in arr[i] with data receive from websocket. How do I make **event.data** to become inp[i] in the first place. So I can match each inp[i] with the arr[i]. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, it was:

```
shifted = inp.shift();
```

Thank you for any help.